# launchd plist for rsync backup

Tags: macos, plist, launchd

I have an rsync2server script that works to completion when run from zsh.

Now I'm trying to make it run at night when my MacBook Air m2 2023 Ventura is sleeping.

First I created a plist to execute the script:

```
pat@Pats-MacBook-Air scripts % cat ~/Library/LaunchAgents/pat.rsync2server.plist 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>pat.rsync2server.plist</string>
    
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/pat/Documents/scripts/stderr.log</string>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/pat/Documents/scripts/stdout.log</string>
    
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string><![CDATA[/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]]></string>
    </dict>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/Users/pat/Documents/scripts/rsync2server.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>55</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Where the time is a couple minutes in the future so it will execute while I watch.

After it executes I get stderr.log:

```
pat@Pats-MacBook-Air scripts % cat stderr.log 
/bin/sh: /Users/pat/Documents/scripts/rsync2server.sh: Operation not permitted
```

If I execute from the terminal:

```
pat@Pats-MacBook-Air scripts % /bin/sh /Users/pat/Documents/scripts/rsync2server.sh
```

Everything works fine.

Do I have a path problem? I'm not familiar with the environment that ~/Library/LaunchAgent launchd and plist use when running.

I load the plist using the id for my gui user "pat".

```
pat@Pats-MacBook-Air scripts % sudo launchctl bootstrap gui/503  Users/pat/Library/LaunchAgents/pat.rsync2server.plist
```

Comment: At least the `Label` value must be specified without the `.plist` extension. And the `EnvironmentVariables` key is actually not needed because `/bin` is a standard path.

Comment: The "Opertation not permitted" must refer to either running `/bin/sh` or executing the script `rsync2seerver.sh` with `/bin/sh` We haven't even gotten into executing the script and rsync itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for "Operation not permitted" was to give `/bin/sh` permission to use the entire disk. AFAIK this is a macOS specific thing that you set in the system settings.

Go to System Settings app (Control Panel for older macOS)->Privacy & Security->Full Disk Access. You will see a panel with programs listed. The only way to get `/bin/sh` into that list is bring up a Finder window and pick the Go To Folder menu and type `/bin/sh` then drag the sh file into System Settings. Make sure the sh entry has the switch on for enabling access--et voila.

After this my plist worked.

Thanks to a responder on Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using using a guid user (the same you use on the shell), maybe is the permissions with rsync.

get it with:  id -u [username]

Load the file on system

```
 sudo launchctl bootstrap gui/501  /Library/LaunchAgents/pat.rsync2server.plist
```

if you make changes on your plist file, try unload it, before load it again with:

```
sudo launchctl bootout gui/501  ~/Library..
```

Comment: Thanks, this tells me how to use boostrap instead of the deprecated "load" but I get the same result, "Operation not permitted" BTW the permission is either running `/bin/sh` or executing the script `rsync2seerver.sh` with `/bin/sh` We haven't even gotten to executing the script and rsync itself.